# Laravel keeps removing the www from my URI, how to stop this?

Tags: url, laravel, uri

i have installed a laravel application onto my hosted solution . now every time i access the site laravel is removing the www from the URI . Example www.example.com becomes example.com. i need the www to stay. please help if you can. thanks.

i have found the following.

here is the url - http://www.example.com/portal?reseller_id=1.

with this URL the www gets removed. but with the following URL it doe not .

http://www.example.com/portal/?reseller_id=1

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's Laravel?  The core/base Laravel code doesn't do any examining of the hostname, and should serve up the application for both the `www` and non-`www` versions of the domain.   It sounds more like you have an `.htaccess` rule setup, or possibly your webhost has a server level configuration, that's removing the www.  I'd test it out with a simple `helloworld.php` file before spending too much time debugging the framework.